# If $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, prove that $\int_0^1 \left |f'(x)-f(x) \right |dx\geq e^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. If $f'$ is continuous, prove that $$\int_0^1 \left |f'(x)-f(x) \right |dx\geq e^{-1}$$

---

#### Progress

I let $h(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$, so that $$\int_0^1 \left |f'(x)-f(x) \right |dx=\int_0^1e^x\left |h'(x) \right |dx$$ But I can't continue from here.. Maybe $$\int_0^1e^x\left |h'(x) \right |dx \geq \max_{x\in [0,1]}e^x\left |h'(x) \right |$$ helps?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks! I let $h(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$, so that $$\int_0^1 \left |f'(x)-f(x) \right |dx=\int_0^1e^x\left |h'(x) \right |dx$$ But I can't continue from here.. Maybe $$\int_0^1e^x\left |h'(x) \right |dx \geq \max_{x\in [0,1]}e^x\left |h'(x) \right |$$ helps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have, $$\begin{align}\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx &= \int_0^1|f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}|e^xdx \\&\geq \int_0^1\left(f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}\right) dx\\&= \int_0^1 \frac{d\left(f(x)e^{-x}\right)}{dx}dx\\&= f(1)e^{-1}-f(0)e^{0}\\&=\frac{1}{e}\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh yeah! That was dumb of my part ;) Thank you very much!